# Calling parent constructor when initialize overridden by included module

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a class hierarchy as follows:

```
class Tree
  def initialize(id, value)
    @id, @value = id, value
  end
end

class Entity < Tree

  include Mongoid::Document

  def initialize(id, value)
    # Do some stuff...
    super(id, value)
  end

end
```

However, calling `super`inside the `Entity#initialize` method calls the `initialize` method located in `Mongoid::Document`, instead of the one in the parent class `Tree`.

How can I call the `Tree#initialize` method from the body of `Entity#initialize`, after the `Mongoid::Document` module has been included?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how Ruby works. When you include a Module ruby implicitly creates an anonymous class and places it above current in the method lookup queue.

Also calling `Entity.ancestors` will show `Mongoid::Document` in the list.

There's a great book I can recommend: `Metaprogramming Ruby` by `Paolo Perotta`

Also here's [a forum thread on a similar topic explaining super stuff](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?pid=25310#p25310)

Update:

If avoiding to call the module constructor is what you want here's a possible trick

```
class Entity < Tree

  def initialize(id, value)
    # Do some stuff...
    # initialize first
    super(id, value)
    # and after that - extend
    extend Mongoid::Document
  end

end
```

This method is not running self.included on the module. If you need this functionality to remain, still not runnin module's initializer the eigenclass can be used in the init:

```
class Entity < Tree

  def initialize(id, value)
    # Do some stuff...
    # initialize first
    super(id, value)
    # and after that - include into eigenclass
    class << self
      include Mongoid::Document
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for making this clearer. But my question is: how can I access the Tree#initialize method from the body of the Entity#initialize method?

Comment: Check the update. The way you include the module can be different.